# BS 4 Toggle Icon swapping

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Does anyone know how to change the bootstrap 4 navbar-toggler-icon when its open vs. closed with css? I thought this would be simple but I cant really find anything on it.

```
.map-controls-mobile .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url('img/mobile-controls-arrow.svg');
    width: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you noticed, navbar-toggler-icon will have the `.collapsed` class if it is collapsed(not opened).
So if you want to change the navbar-toggler-icon when it is open, you may use:

```
button.navbar-toggler.collapsed {
  /* my css code */
}
```

And to change it when it is opened:

```
button.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) {
  /* my css code */
}
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for the answer. Are you sure about this? Im clicking an looking at my inspector and do no see a collapsed class on the toggler. I tired your idea above and it didnt work.

Comment: could you please upload your code here: codepen.io/pen so i can check your code

Comment: Im actually using reactstrap so it may be working differently, sorry man.